# NodeJS framework to properly handle ACID transactions and database concurrency

Tags: node.js, transactions, database-concurrency

I am a beginner in NodeJS world coming from several years working with relational databases in Java / Hibernate.

I would like to use Node for a project, and have spent some time researching about frameworks / ORMs that handle proper database transactions/concurrency such as:

- Ensure ACID transaction blocks (operations set is completely executed or not executed at all)
- Deal with concurrency, i.e. leveraging strategies as optimistic / pessimistic locking

I've looked into some promising ORMs like [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest) and [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline)
as the most promising ones.

- Waterline looks good, but lacks both features mentioned above.
- Sequelize looks much more comprehensive having proper ACID transaction handling. Support for locking and concurrency is absent.

I would like to ask to NodeJS experts about specific patterns or strategies as well as any modules implementing how to deal with a highly concurrent load at database level, cleanly retry failed transactions or ensure data integrity in a HA system.

Comment: this not the best question for SO, see [ask]

Comment: @MartinSerrano I just want to find out how would NodeJS expert solve this problem and some example. Should I reformulate my question?

Comment: sorry, i may have commented to hastily.  the question seems on the edge of what is usually answered here, but it isn't poorly written.  best of luck.

Comment: @MartinSerrano don't worry at all, I want to learn and improve as I am a newbie in this community. Thanks so much for taking the time to read my question and give your opinion.